# Soul separation and diversification

Tags: atma

When how and why did Atman separate from the greater Self and when how and why the diversification into the multitude of sentient beings ? Is this separation and diversification only an illusion ?

Comment: The Jiva tattva or the collection of "multitude of sentient beings" is really the Atman but, because of the limiting form of body and mind, it appears to be a separate entity, just as the space appears to be limited by the jar. If the jar should break, the space that previously “occupied” it is found to be quite unaffected. Similarly, on the death of the body, the Atman remains untouched.

Comment: Jiva is essentially Atman with a covering of gross physical matter - Prakriti. Whereas Atman is Purusha. That's why Samkhya posits the Purusha-Prakriti dichotomy.

Comment: it depends upon which philosophical school of Vedanta you are asking a question about...be more specific

Comment: Ya I am looking for that philosophical school that has an overview of all Vedanta sects. Have all the schools a different answer to how when and why ? And if so why ?

Comment: There are no one school which comprises all the views. Every school has its own view which may be unique and often differs from the view of other schools.